# JRE1.7 issue with BigDecimal

Tags: java, java-7

I am using JRE1.7 update 9 and in my application I am converting amount value from BigDecimal to string. I have kept my locale settings as French(Belgium) with default additional settings.
I am facing a problem with the conversion of this bigdecimal to string. When I click on the amount field it is getting mulitplied by 100 and showing the value in multiples of 100 for eg. if i put value as 52.00 then it modifies this value and shows it as 5200. Only this locale is giving problem. The same scenario is checked with JRE 1.6 but there is no issue like this for this Locale. Only this JRE1.7 is having problem for this particular Locale. Also i am not getting any Exception for this scenario.

Comment: Please post some code, than it will be easier to help you..

Comment: BigDecimal only accepts English Locale and scientific notation in his String constructor (`#,###.##` for example) - how do you parse the string?

Answer (score 3):

In the [Belgian/French locale](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/forms/v3r5m1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.form.designer.locales.doc%2Fi_xfdl_r_formats_fr_BE.html) `.` (period) is a group separator and `,` (comma) is the decimal separator.

In other words, `52.00` is actually `5200`, while `52,00` is 52.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Joachim Isaksson. This same behaviour is tested with JRE1.6 for the same Locale (French(Belgium)).And the behaviour is correct for this JRE. Problem is with JRE1.7 any update where if I have default decimal separator as comma then it does not reflect the same at the application. It takes a dot for decimal separator and digit grouping separator. So any code change may affect the correct behaviour for JRE 1.6 also. Can you pl suggest me  any other solution?

Answer (score 1):

Hi EveryOne I have found the fix for this issue. This issue is from Oracle due to change in Locale.getDefault(). Due to this change the Default Locale is set to en_US even if we choose any other Locale. Please refer to this link for more information on this issue in Oracle bugdatabase.This issue is only for JRE1.7 and not for JRE1.6

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7073906

Thank you.